# Debezium Connect doesnt provide 'before' field after updating an item

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I set up a topic for kafka which emits the data changes which comes from debezium. My db is mongo which is created from *mongo:6* docker image. kafka is created from *confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest*, debezium is from *debezium/connect:2.4*, and zookeeper from *confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest*

Im trying to get the before and after states of the data after update or delete operation to log them.
This is my configuration for topic creation:

```
{
"name": "management-workspaces-deneme",
"config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector",
    "mongodb.connection.string": "mongodb://192.168.2.15:27030",
    "topic.prefix": "eys",
    "capture.mode":"change_streams_with_pre_image",
    "mongodb.poll.interval.ms": "5000",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "172.23.0.3:29092",
    "heartbeat.interval.ms": "5000",
    "database.include.list":"wins",
    "collection.include.list": "wins.workspaces,wins.tasks"
}
```

In debezium's docs, it says ;

`The value of a change event for an update in the sample customers collection has the same schema as a create event for that collection. Likewise, the event value’s payload has the same structure. However, the event value payload contains different values in an update event. An update event includes an after value only if the capture.mode option is set to change_streams_update_full. A before value is provided if the capture.mode option is set to one of the *_with_pre_image option.`

As you can see I added this setting to config. But it doesnt work. I can consume the change and see the message like this

```
"payload":{"before":null,"after":null,"updateDescription":{"removedFields":null,"updatedFields":"{\\"description\\": \\"666teste\\"}",
```

but its before and after field is coming null. How can I see these fields? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know why but I overlooked the part where it says Pre-image support in docs.

[https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/2.4/connectors/mongodb.html#mongodb-pre-image-support:~:text=Pre%2Dimage%20support,*_with_pre_image%20options](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/2.4/connectors/mongodb.html#mongodb-pre-image-support:%7E:text=Pre%2Dimage%20support,*_with_pre_image%20options).

It says I needed to enable changeStreamPreAndPostImages for the collection Im trying to watch. I completely missed this part. After enabling this in mongosh with this command:

```
db.runCommand({
collMod: "workspaces",
changeStreamPreAndPostImages: { enabled: true }
});
```

Im able to see the previous state of the whole document. If only I could get only the updated fields...